# apt-get update : Failed to fetch; Unable to connect to Launchpad

Tags: ppa, repository, launchpad

like 3 hours ago when i type `sudo apt-get update` my repositories update just fine, but now i get these messages :

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease                               

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease         

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg
 Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg       
 Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg       
 Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg       
 Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg       
 Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg       
 Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg
 Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg
 Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg
 Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg
 Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg
 Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http: 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg
 Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/adilson/experimental/ubuntu/dists/natty     /InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexeftimie/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/dev/ubuntu/dists/natty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementaryart/elementarydesktop/ubuntu/dists/natty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/natty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu/dists/natty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists/natty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu/dists/natty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/zeitgeist/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/InRelease   

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/adilson/experimental/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexeftimie/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/am-monkeyd/nautilus-elementary-ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/dev/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementaryart/elementarydesktop/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ferramroberto/java/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu/dists/natty /Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/zeitgeist/ppa/ubuntu/dists/natty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: It seems like Launchpad is down...

Comment: [This answer may help.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44898/where-can-i-see-if-the-server-i-update-from-is-up-to-date/44900#44900)
I suggest you choose another server. Stuff like this happen form time to time.

Answer (score 3):

After reading your post, I just noticed pretty much the same thing. Might be that their server is down for a bit.

Comment: You can check Launchpad status updates at https://twitter.com/launchpadstatus

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and i fixed this issue by setting my ISP's DNS adress manually on
/etc/resolv.conf 
(that is probably another issue why i had dns as 192.168.0.254 from dhcp)
Rafael, might you have same issue?

Comment: @TheEvilPhoenix: DNS is a valid issue, if the DNS server you're using returns a wrong IP or if a firewall is blocking it altogether, such an error may occur. Think a bit out of the box, otherwise it could be closed as "too localised" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu. Arrrghhh. The answer you are looking for is somewhere. Does that help?

```
sudo apt update --option Acquire::Retries=100 \
                --option Acquire::http::Timeout="60"
```