# Where can I see if the server I update from is up to date?

Tags: repository

After talking about this with some people I found out they had newer versions of the software I had but, at that time, I had no updates for my system. A day later those updates did show up and I was able to get the fix that I needed to solve a problem.

So I was wondering if I could find out with a command or at a website if the repositories I use are indeed up to date and/or how long it will take for it to be up to date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Here is a great list](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) of servers status and other useful information.

But if you go to `System -> administartion -> update manager -> Ubuntu software`
and then select `other` in "download from".
then you can select `select best server`.

This gives you the server that is the fastest and up-to-date.

[image: screenshot]