# Reading package list takes forever

Tags: command-line, apt

I've been trying to update my stuff on my machine, and it seems like it can't read my package list. It seems like every time i do the `sudo apt-get install *something* && sudo apt-get update` it gets stuck at reading package list, this have not been a problem before. Here is my specs and whatnot :

- Memory : 15.8 gb
- Processor : AMD Phenom(tm) II x4 965 Processor x 4
- Graphics : Gallium 0.4 on AMD BARTS
- OS type : 32-bit
- Netspeed : [image]

Comment: Just clarifying... you are talking about executing `sudo apt-get update`, correct?

Comment: In `Software Sources`, see if selecting another server, instead of your current one, helps.

Comment: Sorry for not writing more about this problem. But here's the deal! everytime i run a sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade or 'sodu apt-get install *something*' it will get to it eventually, but it takes along 30 minutes ti read thru the list.

Ive tried changing server, and that didnt help.

Comment: What's the specifications of your computer and your internet connection? Edit your question with new information don't add it in the comments...

Comment: btw, why do you have 32-bit on that specification? It makes no sense. I can't figure out your problem though, how many different servers have you tried? This answer might help, http://askubuntu.com/a/44900/10698

Comment: You're not alone. I'm having the same problem. I also found this forum discussion about the problem. Unfortunately there's no resolution. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2104709

Comment: Could you install `strace` and execute `sudo strace -o apt-get.txt apt-get update`? This commands will create a file `apt-get.txt` with all commands it executed. Please copy this to some paste site (http://paste.ubuntu.com) and share the link.

Comment: Very slow network can be caused by defective hardware causing errors and retransmissions.  Look at 'ifconfig -s' (for ethernet level errors) and 'netstat -s' (for TCP/IP level errors).  A non zero error count on the former is almost always a serious problem.

Comment: in my case, doing a `apt-get update` after any change in apt repo list did the trick; without it, `apt install` took ages by (as far as I understand) updating the list each time.

Answer (score 24):

I've seen that as well.

I don't have a solution, but I have a workaround (`echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`) and potentially more information so someone can bring the investigation any further.

It's not a network issue because at *"Reading package list..."*, it is just reading files in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`. A:

```
strace -tt -T -fo strace.log apt-get update
```

gives:

```
16394 14:43:03.921130 open("/var/lib/apt/lists/gb.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-i386_Packages", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 7 <0.000012>
[...]
16394 14:43:03.995238 read(6, "-3.1ubuntu2)\nConflicts: linux86\n"..., 32444) = 32444 <0.000111>
16394 14:43:05.787187 read(6, "c (<< 1:14.b.4-dfsg), erlang-exa"..., 32239) = 32239 <0.000069>
16394 14:43:05.788025 read(6, ".deb\nSize: 42130\nMD5sum: c7de671"..., 31695) = 31695 <0.000068>
16394 14:43:05.870734 read(6, "5: 29c4b395a92bdc12932f151c3643a"..., 31607) = 31607 <0.000071>
16394 14:43:05.890862 read(6, "e-pack-af-base\nFilename: pool/ma"..., 32538) = 32538 <0.000070>
16394 14:43:05.891425 read(6, "buntu-usb-live, ubuntu-dvd-live,"..., 32090) = 32090 <0.000066>
16394 14:43:05.891960 read(6, "cd9755b03ac2c9b8251125c7b6618\nDe"..., 32195) = 32195 <0.000034>
16394 14:43:06.043001 read(6, "rg>\nArchitecture: all\nVersion: 2"..., 32535) = 32535 <0.000072>
```

See how those 8 `read` system calls took over 2 seconds even though each individual call takes less than 1 ms.
Running `time apt-get update` or looking at `top`, that process is not busy between those two calls. So why the delay?

Then I did:

```
echo t > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

a few times and looked at the outcome in `kern.log`:

```
 apt-get         D 00000000     0 16790  12706 0x00000000
  e8695d30 00000086 f7bd5e6c 00000000 f7bd5e44 f74a6580 c1990e00 c1990e00
  efe46efe 000042cb f7b9de00 e71a7230 f74a6580 c107e116 00000000 00000000
  044aa200 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 e8695d0c e8695d0c c1038de8
 Call Trace:
  [<c107e116>] ? enqueue_entity+0x186/0x220
  [<c1038de8>] ? default_spin_lock_flags+0x8/0x10
  [<c15e13bd>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irqsave+0x2d/0x40
  [<c15e0533>] schedule+0x23/0x60
  [<c15deecf>] schedule_timeout+0x12f/0x290
  [<c1075c38>] ? ttwu_do_activate.constprop.86+0x58/0x70
  [<c1055190>] ? usleep_range+0x40/0x40
  [<c15e0846>] io_schedule_timeout+0x86/0xd0
  [<c15cef7d>] balance_dirty_pages.isra.17+0x3f5/0x4b4
  [<c15e118d>] ? _raw_spin_lock+0xd/0x10
  [<c1180781>] ? __set_page_dirty_buffers+0x81/0xb0
  [<c110deb5>] ? set_page_dirty+0x55/0x60
  [<c11812c9>] ? __block_page_mkwrite+0xe9/0x170
  [<c110f3ae>] balance_dirty_pages_ratelimited_nr+0xde/0x100
  [<c1126f53>] do_wp_page+0x503/0x830
  [<c1128ef7>] handle_pte_fault+0x267/0x2c0
  [<c1129c62>] handle_mm_fault+0x1e2/0x280
  [<c15e4988>] do_page_fault+0x158/0x4c0
  [<c104e4dc>] ? irq_exit+0x5c/0xa0
  [<c15e22d0>] ? do_debug+0x180/0x180
  [<c15e4830>] ? vmalloc_fault+0x195/0x195
  [<c15e1c53>] error_code+0x67/0x6c
```

So, not sure what that means but that looks about the handling of page faults, so points at a potential memory management issue.

I then tried a:

```
echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

And that did make the problem go away.

Now, it very much looks like a kernel issue. So, I've updated to the latest kernel (3.8 backport from `raring`) and that's where I'm at. Will update if the problem persists with the newer kernel.

#### Edit

The problem does persist with the new kernel, though not as bad. And same thing,

```
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

clears the problem for a while. I've only seen that happen on MSI laptops (Product Name: CR61 2M/CX61 2OC/CX61 2OD).

#### Edit December 2015

As confirmed by `btrace` `aptitude`/`apt-get` does appear to do some disk I/O at the time. It's got a temporary file (`/var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin.<random-chars>`) mmapped in memory which is why it doesn't show in the `strace` output.

Still can't explain why it only happens on some machines only, why dropping caches helps, why switching to 64bit helps.

If somebody can reproduce it, an interesting test could be to see if that also happens when running under `eatmydata` or if moving `/var/cache/apt` onto `tmpfs` or a ramdisk helps.

Comment: On 5th of April, 2014 I can confirm that the problem still exists. Tested on: Linux Mint 16, 32 bit, running on 64 bit processor, Lenovo W520, and: Kubuntu 12.10 32 bit, again running on 64 bit hardware, custom built desktop. (and the solution/workaround suggested here also works :) )

Comment: @fritzone, I remember seeing the problem reported elsewhere where people were saying that switching to a 64bit OS fixed the problem.

Comment: I plan to switch back to a 64 bit OS too. Before, on the desktop I had a 64 bit version of 12.10 and had no problems like this.

Comment: The problem still exists on ubuntu 14.04 :-(. Your solution with echo 3 to drop_caches worked. This has happened after some very buggy behavior of Inkscape with clipboard incorrectly clashing with Netbeans when it has opened 100 msgboxes or so... Even though Inkscape was killed, it left some mess in the system which totally slowed down apt-get reading the packages.

Comment: I see it sometime too, and the workaround do not work for me. It is a 64 bit operating system here, on a samsung laptop with i7 and 8G ram. Only a reboot make the problem go away. Weird.

Comment: I also confirm that this still happens with 32bit OS running with kernel 3.13.0-32-generic on Ubuntu 12.04 precise. Hardware is an Intel Xeon E3-1220. Reported on jul/2015. The 'echo 3' resolved the issue.

Comment: I have seen this on Debian Jessie running 32-bit and can confirm that the `drop_caches` workaround fixed it immediately. `3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2`.  FWIW it's an MSI motherboard.

Comment: For anyone's reference. I had enormous TLB shutdowns while this happened and really slow hard drive performance (even though it was hard-raid array). Grading system to 64 bit completely fixed this issue for me. Also TLB shutdowns value lowered greatly since then.

Answer (score 5):

The advice at http://antti-juhani.kaijanaho.fi/newblog/archives/521 has sped it up for me several times on various computers:

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail
sudo sync-available
```

(The blog also recommended `sudo dpkg --forget-old-unavail` between the 2 steps but apparently it's deprecated and no longer needed.)

Comment: Yes it worked amazing

Answer (score 4):

Follow the steps:

- Clean out cache:

  ```
  sudo apt-get clean
  ```
- Move the `sources.list` so `apt` cannot use it:

  ```
  mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list1 && sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Move it back then update:

  ```
  mv /etc/apt/sources.list1 /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo apt-get update
  ```

Also check and remove any PPAs and source lines you don't need.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, the cause was an incorrect value in the `LANGUAGE=` environment variable. It should hold values such as `en:fr:de`, and not `en_US.UTF-8,sl_SI.UTF-8`:

```
root@fik:~
# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8,sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_TIME=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_NAME=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

When ran (via `strace`), the `apt-get update` command clonks on the `read()` call. It takes ages to execute, and eats all the available cycles of one CPU core:

```
root@fik:~
# strace apt-get update
[snip]
read(5, "form, hardware::opengl, implemen"..., 32146) = 32146
read(5, " Maintainers <pkg-bluetooth-main"..., 32658) = 32658
read(5, ": 17569748\nMD5sum: 9c20d52f9a0d5"..., 32200) = 32200
brk(0x55ac79212000)                     = 0x55ac79212000
read(5, "scription-md5: ca1156b27bec24d4c"..., 32469) = 32469
read(5, " Boost.Math Library\nMulti-Arch: "..., 32477) = 32477
read(5, "epends: libc6 (>= 2.4), lsb-base"..., 32648) = 32648
^C--- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
strace: Process 18452 detached
```

If I set `LANGUAGE=` to a correct value (such as `en`), everything goes back to normal again:

```
root@fik:~
# export LANGUAGE=en

root@fik:~
# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_TIME=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_NAME=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=sl_SI.UTF-8
LC_ALL=

root@fik:~
# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian experimental InRelease
Ign:3 http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian jessie InRelease                                                      
Hit:4 http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian jessie-updates InRelease  
Hit:5 http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian jessie-backports InRelease                                                                             
Hit:6 http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian sid InRelease                                                                    
Hit:7 http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian stretch InRelease                               
Hit:8 http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian stretch-updates InRelease                                             
Hit:9 http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian jessie Release                                  
Hit:2 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb InRelease                           
Hit:10 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease      
Hit:11 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Oh, and of course I put the incorrect value there myself a few years ago. Funnily enough, *apt* was working flawlessly until yesterday, after II *apt-get upgrade*'d the system (Debian sid).

Comment: I've suddenly encountered this on a 32-bit install of Debian Jessie that's been working for years (decades?). Nothing's change in the machine configuration, but it suddenly started happening.  I don't have LANGUAGE= set to anything, though.  Setting it to "en" or using C for all LC_* locale variables didn't help yet.